TypeScript - Convert types to interfaces. 10% gave errors. Fixed with Record<> - Correct? Or Fluke?
Upgrading our codebase to latest ESLint for TypeScript. One problem rule was:
@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-definitions. I was missing 62 of these. Simple changing brought this down to 12, but those 12 had errors when I change them to interface from type:
Error: projects/.../MyCodeFile.ts:123:50 - error TS2769: No overlaod matches this call.
<samples of the overloads>
.get<MyClassName>(uriStringVariable, {params})

Here params was underlined as the error. This seemed to be the source-error causing many other errors.

Solution 1
I found that the params was an indexed type, so I tried adding that to the interface:
export interface MyInterfaceChangedFromType extends Record<string, string> {
    myVar: string;
}

This worked (let me know if it's only masking the error!) in all but one cases. The problem case was where I had an optional element:
export interface MyInterfaceChangedFromType extends Record<string, string> {
    addressLine1: string;
    addressLine2?: string;
}


Solution 2
To solve for the second problem I had to make the export line as follows:
export interface MyInterfaceChangedFromType extends Record<string, string | any> {
    addressLine1: string;
    addressLine2?: string;
}

though this does not help with getting rid of 'any' from the code.

Ask
Please let me know if the above was just fluke an is only hiding an existing problem? And if there is a better alternative than using | any in the second solution.

Please [edit] to provide a [mre] so we can test approaches before suggesting them. Right now we're missing the code and even the error message looks like you typed it yourself ("overlaod") so we can't reproduce what you've got here. I'd say you could write Record<string, string | undefined>, noting that string | any is just any and Record<string, any> is quite loose.  Aside from that, it's not really possible to know if you're hiding an existing problem (since we don't see your problem) or if string | undefined or indeed even if indexable types are the way to proceed.
